# hide overflow-y only for a certain page

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a page that has scrolling bars and I know that for removing them,

```
body {
    overflow: hidden; 
}
```

will solve the problem.
The thing is that this code affects all the pages from the app, and I want only for this certain page to remove the scroll.

Comment: add a class to the body on that page and apply styling to the class or is that not an option?

Answer (score 3):

You have several options here:

**1. Add an ID to your `<body>` tag:**

HTML:

`<body id="pageID">...</body>`

CSS:

```
#pageID {
    overflow: hidden; 
}
```

**2. Add an additional class to the body of the page, where your CSS is needed:**

HTML:

`<body class="additionalClass">...</body>`

CSS:

```
.additionalClass {
    overflow: hidden; 
}
```

**3. Add your CSS code directly to the HTML where it is needed using `<style>` tags:**

HTML:

```
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            overflow: hidden; 
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>...</body>
```

**4. Add inline-CSS code directly to your `<body>` tag:**

HTML:

`<body style="overflow: hidden;">...</body>`

Answer (score 1):

So you need to apply this CSS property (overflow) only on certain page. You can do it several ways :

- having a different CSS file depending on pages
- apply this CSS property to an id or a class, and have this id/class apply on the body of the pages you don't want a scroll

Example CSS file :

```
.no-scroll, #no-scroll{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Example HTML file :

```
<html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body id='no-scroll' class='no-scroll'>...</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to add inline CSS in body tags of every page